# Нет перевода на странице подтверждения человечности

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, recaptcha

Нет перевода на странице с проверкой на робота.(я много раз обновлял страницу)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выполнил [перевод](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/143131357?q=key%3A882b4d6b5c9c7b0d8fa0c8523d9947e6):

> **Вы настоящий человек?** Приносим извинения за возникшую путаницу, но мы не можем *точно* определить, человек вы или робот. Пожалуйста, не воспринимайте это лично. Боты и скрипты могут быть необычайно реалистичны в наши дни!

Появится на сайте после подкачки базы и пересборки движка.

Comment: Предлагаю пару правок: «**Вы настоящий человек?** Приносим извинения за возникшую путаницу, но мы не можем _точно_ определить, человек вы или робот. Пожалуйста, не воспринимайте это лично: боты и скрипты могут быть необычайно реалистичными в наши дни!». 1) двоеточие, которое связывает обращение и пояснение к нему, 2) форма прилагательного _реалистичный_ изменена с краткой на полную (из стилистических соображений). Если вы не согласны, пожалуйста, сообщите об этом.

Comment: @Aer предложения разбиты по оригинальной строке. Насчёт второго пункта не возражаю.