# Проверка на робота

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, предложение, recaptcha

Писал я тут ответ, писал, и вдруг вылезает мне такое странное сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня два вопроса, точнее один вопрос и одно предложение.

**Вопрос**: из-за чего это?
**Предложение:** Подкорректировать это окно. Потому что когда оно вылезло, я сначала даже подумал, что здесь что-то не чисто и я кому-то куда-то как-то на что-то попался <strike>и вообще это проделки russian hackers</strike>. Дело в том, что стиль (не текст и не суть) данного окна, на мой взгляд, совершенно <strike>уродливый</strike> *аляповатый* по сравнению с остальным сайтом:

1. *Вообще* непонятная картинка слева. *Что* это за робот? *Что* он здесь забыл? *Что* за AR⋅TUR? На этой коробке, насколько я смог разглядеть, надпись даже не на английском!
2. *Что* с текстом? *Почему* текст так сильно придвинут к картинке, что еще 2 пикселя, и он на нее залезет? Это что ли красиво? В оригинале этого судя по [этому](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7182/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8) вопросу нет.
3. Само поле капчи почему-то тоже присосалось к этой картинке.
4. Где здесь **вообще** логотип SO или ruSO? Как я реально должен понять, что это именно запрос от сайта, а не какой-то мошеннический прототип сайта или уловка? Я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в кибермошенничестве, однако почему я **вообще** должен нажимать на какую-то галочку, которая не пойми откуда вылезла в непонятном окне со страшной картинкой и кривой разметкой? **Где лого нашего сайта, чтобы было понятно, что это запрос от него?**

Я понимаю, что существует вероятность того, что мое предложение, если оно полезно, может быть неосуществимо со стороны модераторов ruSO, поэтому об этом, возможно, лучше написать на изначальный сайт, однако я могу ошибаться, ибо там я не смог воспроизвести подобную ошибку.

Comment: [Здесь](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348240/339911) тоже широкое окошко, и нет отступов. Но из-за закруглённой картинки не так бросается в глаза. [Тут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355038/339911) ещё одна версия, уже с отступом, но неожиданно большим по моему мнению.

Comment: По первой ссылке картинка в разы лучше: не яркая (т.е. не бросается в глаза), спокойная, без лишней информации - текста, робота со страшными красными глазами, как будто будет лазерами стрелять:)  А вот по второй ссылке текст же вылезает из окна! Тут мне кажется итак понятно, что все плохо.

Comment: Это когда фронтендеру сказали сделать фичу, но не дали дизайн. И он сделал, как это видел. И картинка зачетная!

Comment: `Я понимаю, что существует вероятность того, что мое предложение, если оно полезно, может быть неосуществимо со стороны модераторов ruSO, поэтому об этом, возможно, лучше написать на изначальный сайт, однако я могу ошибаться, ибо там я не смог воспроизвести подобную ошибку.` — так оно и не осуществимо с точки зрения модераторов. У модераторов есть инструменты для модерации, а не для переписывания сайта. Зато у нас (кажется) есть Николас — CM. И вот вполне может осуществить я думаю.

Comment: Понятно, ТС - робот

Comment: Идея для стартапа — сделать вредоносное браузерное расширение, которое будет подсовывать на сайты такие окошки с капчей (но с нормальным дизайном), заразить достаточное число устройств и запустить API для разгадывания капч с помощью заражённых))

Comment: @yolosora, ага, робот Вертер 

Comment: @andreymal Намек на то, что такого не существует?

Comment: @МаксимФисман не, я просто глупые шуточки пишу) А так вроде [существует](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352994)

Comment: О, у меня давно такого не было, а раньше раза два в месяц вылазило. Видимо, человечней стал.

Comment: на мой взгляд модули ИИ по отгадке капч уже давно существуют, почему их не внедряют?

Comment: @Эникейщик А из-за чего такое происходит? У меня, например, впервые за более, чем 6 месяцев на сайте?

Comment: @andreymal сегодня в этих ваших компуктерах все возможно:)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Вы имеете ввиду [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky)?

Comment: А кого же?.. ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor ну мало ли? Я не знаю списка сотрудников-модераторов сайта. Может и он сюда заглянет:)

Comment: Вряд ли, кажется даже более важные (ИМХО) запросы игнорируются...

Comment: В общем суть я так понимаю пугать всех роботов и тех кто на них похож ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Ага, пугать роботов фотографией другого робота-поработителя человечества :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Я не знаю, почему я комментирую свой же вопрос спустя почти месяц, однако в ответ на ваши ссылки: правильно ли я понимаю, что такая проблема присутствует на enSO? Если да, будет ли все же нужным написать туда? Если нет, то как это возможно? Русский текст, в отличие от английского, не уместился в окошко и оно съехало что ли?

Comment: @МаксимФисман напишите, лишним не будет. В худшем случае заминусуют или закроют дубликатом :)